# Changing root password in of Virtual Machine KVM

Tags: linux, security, virtual-machine, virtualization, openstack

I was curious as DigitalOcean provide us with root password reset option, as I have been working towards virtualization about 3 months and never came across direct way to do so.

Like openstack offers such option only for xen, where as if I am not wrong Digital Ocean provides for KVM. Also proxmox and other stacks do not provide this option. 
So I need to know how these guys managed to do so.

One thing I know is that if I can access the file system then I can edit the shadow file but, In virtual environment Machine is in templete form not in Open File system state.

I was wondering if there is any root backdoor in OS itself provided by DO using which they change password on request ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off your virtal machine, all you have is the whole "virtual hard drive" file on "real hard drive" in a real machine. It's a common file system that can be parsed and managed from outside with no problem (unless it is encrypted).

So there's no reason for you to NOT be able to access the filesystem of the virtual machine, including the shadow file.

Comment: What I have is qcow2 file, any idea for that ?

Comment: once it's open source, I think you can find good documentation on it. I just found this (https://people.gnome.org/~markmc/qcow-image-format.html), but I don't know if it's complete. I suggest you  to use something like "010 Editor", a good hexadecimal editor, so you can explore the file raw data. If you desire, write a template on it, so you can easily navigate over the file structures and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done using cloudinit... No hackery involved